# Unicode string comparison being interpreted as unequal (Python/Django app)

Tags: python, django, unicode, python-2.x

this is probably a pretty basic question for some of you, but is causing me some big headaches in a live environment.

I have a Django-based social networking website, where among other things, I also maintain a list of usernames in a separate file (called verified.py) like so:

```
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4',]
```

These usernames get special treatment on my website (e.g. a badge). Every now and then, a user has special non-ASCII characters in their username, e.g. `Š0nîКa`. If I try to include such usernames in the list above, *new relic* shows an error rate escalating to 100%; the exception being: **exceptions:SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc5' in file /app/verified.py on line 1, but no encoding declared;**

I read the PEP accompanying this, I'm to add a magic line at the top: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- I did this, yet the following warning happened:

**After UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  '==': infix(10, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) == y.eval(context)),**

Looked around in SO, didn't exactly nail how to take care of this. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `u''` prefix to mark the names as unicode strings, e.g. `u'Š0nîКa'`.

In Python 2 without the `u''` prefix, they are treated as byte strings, and the warning explains that Python hit an error when trying to convert them to unicode.

Comment: Oh really? Hold on, I'll give it shot

Comment: Perfect. And I can't accept your answer before 7 more mins :P